# txt data cleaning up with pandas and regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, oracle, dataframe

I'm super beginner but I was trying to do a python scrypt which would pull the data which I am interested in from the txt file which I usually download from the oracle software.
Typically, when I copy paste it into excel it's fine, but when I try to open it with pandas the data is a mess.

What I need to do is to get number of each unit, its cost and depreciation reserve (marked with yellow).
[image]

I tried using this code to begin with but it seems that for some reason python reads the data in wrong way, it creates so many columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

regex = 'I?N?\d{6,7}-'

df = pd.read_table('process data.txt', delim_whitespace=True, encoding='latin-1')
df['merged'] = df['COMPAN'] + df['COMPANCOMPANNY,']
series = df['merged']

df1 = series.str.contains(regex)

df['check'] = df1
df
```

And the output is really bad:

[image]

So do you have any hints how to even start actually? I was thinking that maybe there is a way load the table from TXT and divide it into columns based on established width? I was also looking for that solution but couldn't find any.

Here is a SkyDrive link [EXAMPLE FILE](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AqTGjOBznBqagSs9HNo68cbXG28m?e=FWiElW) and the same sample pasted as a text: https://pastebin.pl/view/d3b2b4f8

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include your sample data as text, not as a picture or a link to external site. In this case, it seems like you might get a good result if you skip the header rows with the `skiprows` parameter in the `read_csv`

Comment: Thanks for advice. I added pastebin link. I also tried to skiprows but the output for pretty much the same OR I was doing something wrong there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not exactly be what you are looking for but maybe it helps.

I would pre-process the data before loading into a DataFrame. With the example file from the link I did the following:

```
import re
re_row = re.compile(r'^.*?\s+'
                    r'(?P<id>\d+).*\s+[\d,.]+\s+'
                    r'(?P<cost>[\d,.]+)\s+[\d,.]+\s+[\d,.]+\s+'
                    r'(?P<depr_res>[\d,.]+)\s+[\d,.]+$',
                    re.VERBOSE)

data = []
with open('process data.txt', 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        if re_row.match(line):
            id, cost, depr_res = re_row.match(line).groups()
            data.append([int(id),
                         float(cost.replace(',', '')),
                         float(depr_res.replace(',', ''))])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'cost', 'depr_res'])
```

The resulting frame looks like

```
         id      cost  depr_res
0    123123  11448.08  11448.08
1    123124  23950.12  23950.12
2    123125  23950.12  23950.12
3    123126  11448.08  11448.08
4   1353000  17001.08  14830.16
5   1353001  17001.08  14830.16
6   1353002  17001.08  11688.19
7   1353003  17001.08  14566.06
8   1353004  17001.08   9194.67
9   1353005  17001.08  14830.16
10  1353006  17001.08  14830.16
...
```

This is in no way a full-fledged solution(!), but maybe a starting point to work on.

Comment: Man, you are the magician. I used it on my production data with 10k+ rows and it matched to report perfectly. Not gonna lie, I don't understand what you did there but I will analysi it line by line. Thank you!

Comment: @gervith Glad I could help a bit. If you're interested in how the regex works look [here](https://regex101.com/r/uS1BQl/2).

Comment: Excellent use of python regex!  Thank you for the example.  Here's a good reference which I think goes nicely with the answer: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html